# How to get the sales email order copy programmatically in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I'm developing a magento module and I need to get the sales email order copy field in Magento.    How can access to the copy email field programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked long ago, just want to leave information for someone else having same question.

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_email/order/copy_to');
```

If you have multiple email addresses you should split them, and turn them into array before passing on to sendTransactional.